# Gradient like this?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I'm not UI designer so I can't feel xml colors enough, I want to make gradient like this:

http://t1.uccdn.com/en/images/6/5/2/img_2256_ins_45517_600.jpg

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#1f313d"

            android:endColor="#2c3942"
            android:angle="135"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

but... I think that 2 colors are not enough, how to make it similar gradieñt to this image then? *last screen

Comment: I presume this was made in photoshop or illustrator and just exported as an image and then used for a background here.

Comment: Maybe they used photoshop but images are very heavy ;)

Comment: @ramzixp it use Kens Burn effect,https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How to create Gradient ??

**Create Gradient is very easy**

1. Right click on `drawable` folder and create `xml` file.
2. Create shape Tag
3. Inside shape tag create gradient tag

Gradient Properties........

```
android:startColor="put here your color"
android:endColor="put here your color"
android:centerColor="put your color here"
android:angle="45"
```

**if you need gradient in**

> horizontal way put angle = "0"
>
> vertical way put angle = "90"
>
> corner horizontal way put angle = "45"
>
> and opposite of corner horizontal way put angle = "135"

use this .......

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <gradient android:startColor="#915d5b"
        android:endColor="#418c47"
        android:angle="45"></gradient>
</shape>
```

[image: output]

enjoy coding.......

Answer (score 2):

Or you could simply use Gradient Generator tools at [AngryTools](http://angrytools.com), which is much easier and fun to use.